# Approximate a poisson binomial distribution with a binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have samples of Bernoulli distributed variable that are neither the first nor the second i in iid. My goal is to model their sum.

I got from Wikipedia that I can use the poisson binomial distribution to make up for one of the i's, but then I have to keep all the inidividual probabilities.

It would probably also be possible to throw the central limit theorem against it somehow to model it as a Gaussian, but I wonder if I can do better.

Are there any results on how well a binomial distribution fits the sum of non identically non independently distributed Bernoulli samples. Especially if I can get some bounds on the accuracy wrt the correlation of the samples or something like that.

Comment: See this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/how-can-i-efficiently-model-the-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables

Comment: The answer depends, in an essential manner, on precisely *how* your observations depart from independence and how they fail to be identically distributed.  In general the binomial distribution, with a single parameter, is too "rigid" to model your sum: you should be looking at families with more parameters to allow for under- or over-dispersion.  Perhaps you could tell us more about these data?