# Sum of Bernoulli variables with different success probabilities

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, convolution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Let $x_i$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with success probabilities $p_i$. That is, $x_i=1$ with probability $p_i$ and $x_i=0$ with probability $1-p_i$.

Is there a closed expression or an approximate formula for the distribution of the sum $\sum_i x_i$?

Comment: If the $p_i$ are very small, you can use Poisson approximation. Let $X_i\sim \mbox{Be}(p_i)$ be independent and let $Y\sim\mbox{Po}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^np_i$. In a [classic paper by Hodges and Le Cam](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177705799) it is shown that
$|\mbox{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leq x)-\mbox{P}(Y\leq x)|=3\cdot (\max_{1\leq i\leq n}p_i)^{1/3}.$ If the $p_i$ are all close to 0, this difference is small.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, solutions appear at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41247 (computational methods) and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347 (approximations for large numbers of variables).

Comment: @MånsT Hodges and Le Cam's result you state is incorrect. The equality is less than or equal to!!.

Comment: @Chamberlain: you are absolutely right! I can't edit it now though, as my comment is too old.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, in fact, the distribution is known as the [Poisson binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), which is a generalization of the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). The distribution's mean and variance are intuitive and are given by

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\sum_i x_i\right] &= \sum_i E[x_i] = \sum_i p_i\\
V\left[\sum_i x_i\right] &= \sum_i V[x_i] = \sum_i p_i(1-p_i).
\end{align}
$$

The expectation is straightforward because it is a linear operator. The variance is also straightforward because of the independence assumption.

Comment: And if you sum up "enough" of those 0/1 random variables, you can approximate the resulting poisson binomial with a normal distribution with the same mean and variance. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375886/approximating-poisson-binomial-distribution-with-normal-distribution

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a closed formula to exist. If n becomes relevant you can apply Central Theorem Limit so approximating the sum distribution with a normal distribution having mean the sum of p_i and variance the sum of p_i * ( 1 - p_i).

Comment: The CLT often fails (that is, does not even apply) in this circumstance unless the $p_i$ remain away from $0$ and $1$.