# Distribution of a linear combination of Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, bernoulli-distribution

I am trying to calculate the expectation of absolute value of a linear combination of independent Bernoulli random variables, $E(|a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ...+ a_nx_n|)$. In particular, $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ are the coordinates of a unit vector.

Of course if all $a_i = 1$ we got Binomial distribution but I am wondering for general coefficients $a_1, ..., a_n$ whether the sum $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ...+ a_nx_n$ would follow any distribution that I can easily get the expectation of absolute value.

Comment: Some closely related posts with relevant information are https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41247.

Comment: They are very informative indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Y = \sum a_iX_i$.

In general the cost of computing $\mathbb{E}(|Y|)$ exactly will likely grow exponentially with $n$, because calculating $\mathbb{P}(|Y| = y)$ involves deciding whether there exists a subset of the $a_i$ whose sum is either $y$ or $-y$, which is the NP-complete [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

There are variants of the Central Limit Theorem for non-identically distributed independent random variables like your $a_iX_i$, such as the [Lyapunov CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT). Based on this, for large $n$ you could try approximating $Y$ with a normal distribution with mean $\sum{a_ip}$ and variance $\sum{a_i^2p(1-p)}$, and $|Y|$ with the corresponding [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).

But this will be innaccurate if most of the variance in $Y$ comes from only a few of the $a_i$ - for example, if one of the $a_i$ is much larger in magnitude than all the others then the distribution of $Y$ will be bimodal rather than normal. (If your unit vector is uniformly chosen from the $n$-dimensional unit sphere this is unlikely to happen for large $n$. A random unit vector can be chosen by taking coordinates from $n$ i.i.d. normal distributions and normalising the results, and since normal distributions have thin tails, it's unlikely that a small number of these coordinates will be significantly bigger than the rest.)

It might be easiest to just approximate the expectation using Monte Carlo (simulate $|Y|$ many times and take the mean of the simulations).

Comment: Yeah Monte Carlo simulation seems to be a fast and practical solution, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You might try the saddlepoint approximation, see [How does saddlepoint approximation work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781).  For that we need the mfg (moment generating function) and its logarithm, the cgf (cumulant generating function.) The mgf for a single Bernoulli variable $p$, is $(1-p)+p e^t$.  So the mgf for $a_i X_i$ is $(1-p)+p e^{a_i t}$.

But we are interested in the absolute value of the sum, so let us split the sum in parts after the sign of the $a_i$'s. Let $I_+, I_-$ be the sets of indices with positive and negative coefficients. Then
$$ | Y | = Y_+ - Y_- $$ where
$Y_+=\sum_{i\in I_+} a_i X_i$ and $Y_- =\sum_{i\in I_-} a_i X_i$. We get the mgf's
$$ M_+(t) =\prod_{i\in I_+}\left( (1-p)+p e^{a_i t} \right) \\
   M_-(t) =\prod_{i\in I_+}\left( (1-p)+p e^{a_i t} \right) 
$$The cgf $M_\pm(t)$ are the logarithms of the mgf's, and finally the cgf of the absolute value is
$$
K_{|Y|}(t)= K_+(t) + K_-(-t).
$$