# Should I use a one-sided or a two-sided confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, simulation, monte-carlo

**Context:**
I am teaching a subject and I prepared a multiple-choice quiz for my students.
To have a feeling for which is an acceptable grade I decided to compute a baseline score, which is the score that an agent that answers completely at random would get on the same quiz.
For that, I ran a Monte Carlo simulation and generated N scores for that agent.

Now my goal is to find a value (i.e. a score) that gives me enough confidence/evidence to make me say: "this student did not answer at random". For that, I wanted to compute a 95% confidence interval on these values.

**Question:**
The question is: in this case does it make more sense to compute the one-sided confidence interval or the two-sided? What each of them does actually tell me? I am not able to really tell which would be the difference for me between these two options.

Also, I realized that if I compute the two-sided confidence interval, the lower boundary is always 0, which means that that 2.5% fraction on the left is all 0s. Does this affect the decision?

I feel like I am not really interested in the lower boundary, but on the other hand if I do a one-left CI, the upper boundary is lower which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Why are you doing a Monte Carlo simulation at all? If you have a multiple choice exam, there are analytic solutions to this. Also, I would question that guessing at random has much to do with an "acceptable score".

Comment: How many questions does the quiz have, how many answers are there per question and how are they scored?

Comment: @PeterFlom because it is a simulation and it is easier for me since I am more a programmer than a mathematician. The score of the "random agent" is not the acceptable score, his score would be the baseline and I would expect students to do better than that.

Comment: @COOLSerdash It does not really matter, I want a solution that applies to any quiz I might make. However I am considering a scenario in which there are between 10 and 15 questions with 4-5 options each and only 1 correct answer that gives a positive score, while the incorrect options simply score 0.

Comment: You are asking for a *quantile* of the distribution of random scores: it is not a "confidence interval."  The latter is computed from a *random sample,* which is not an issue here.  // Your question is answered in several threads, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/risk-of-extinction-of-schr%c3%b6dingers-cats, which gives the *full distribution* of correct scores, even when there are different numbers of possible responses in each question. When the number of responses is constant, that is a Binomial distribution.