# Binomial distribution for randomly drawn probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, composite, compound-distributions

## Main question

Probability theory can be a weird place sometimes. Here I was, confident in my insane math skills, trying to solve the following problem:
Let $N, \alpha$ and $\beta$ be given.

- Draw $N$ coins from a fixed bag with different coins, such that the success probability for each coin is unknown but modeled by a Beta distribution $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$.
- Flip each coin from the bag once and count the number of successes.

How are the number of successes distributed?

---

## What I have tried so far

Based on some googling I thought it should be the [Beta-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) distribution!". But this quick Python implementation:

```py
sample_size = 2**20

N = 42
alpha = 3.14159
beta  = 2.71828

coins = np.random.beta(alpha, beta, size=N)

sample = []
for i in range(sample_size):
    R = np.random.uniform(size=N)
    wins = np.sum(np.where(coins>R, 1, 0))
    sample.append(wins)
```

leads to the histogram:

[image]

Instead, it seemed like the simulated distribution just resembles a "normal" binomial distribution:

[image]

where $\hat{\mu}$ is the sample mean. However, a simple [$\chi^2$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) rejects this hypothesis:

```py
>>> cats, f_obs = zip(*[(cat, len(list(group))) for cat,group in groupby(sorted(sample))])
>>> f_exp = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(k=cats, n=N, p=np.mean(sample)/N)*sample_size
>>> 
>>> scipy.stats.chisquare(f_obs=f_obs, f_exp=f_exp)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=14303.936045316765, pvalue=0.0)
```

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9545/237341) but @probabilityislogic seems to be suggesting to do exactly what I have done.

**My question now is**: What kind of distributions are generated by this experiment and why is it not the Beta-Binomail distribution?

Comment: I figured so far, that the Beta-Binomial distribution is suited for ["the binomial distribution in which the probability of success at each trial is **fixed** but randomly drawn from a beta distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution), whereas in my case the coins are drawn newly after each trial and hence results to a different distribution.

Comment: Isn't that a sum of Beta-Binomial variates?

Comment: Hm... you mean it's the sum of independent Beta-Binomial distributions, with $N=1$?
That would make sense...

Comment: @Xi'an but isn’t the Beta-Binomial for $n=1$ just a Bernoulli distribution? That would mean that the sum should be binomially distributed...

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you use precisely the same $42$ probabilities (`coins`) in each of the $2^{20}$ simulations, and so lose the element of sample variance which would come from these varying

You would get the Beta-Binomial distribution if you chose new probabilities each time,  for example putting

```
coins = np.random.beta(alpha, beta, size=N)
```

inside the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for this insight! 
I guess my question then is not well posed. In my actual problem where I need this the bag of coins indeed is fixed, and we only know that the success probabilities of the (unknown but fixed) coins are modeled by a Beta-distribution.

Comment: I modified the question box now.