# Probability distribution with different probabilities and possible outcomes

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

I want to know how I can model a distribution that is basically *n* Bernoulli trials. However, these Bernoulli trials can have different probabilities and outcomes.

It is basically the same question as asked here: [Probability distribution for different probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/probability-distribution-for-different-probabilities), with the addition of the possible different outcomes.

The eventual goal is to give a confidence interval on a measure of a set of *n* predicted revenue streams with it's own size and probability.

Is it even possible to define a confidence interval or define a distribution when the individual Bernoulli trials that make it up have different possible outcomes?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "different outcomes"?

Comment: It's certainly possible to define confidence intervals and distributions for this case, but there's unlikely to be a simple formula for them. I don't think there's much to say here in the absence of more information on the probabilities in the Bernoulli trials.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494302/high-dimensional-bernoulli-factory/494539#494539