# What is the name and formalism of this discrete distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution, distribution-identification, discrete-distributions

I am searching the name of something similar to a binomial distribution, but with individual probabilities (P(1) to P(N)).

I calculated (brute-forced with a script) the probability of k positive outcomes of N binary events of known (different) probabilities the following way:

Once N individual probabilities (for N binary events) were estimated, the exact probability of k observed positive outcomes in a distribution of all N+1 possible combined outcomes (totals), was calculated as the sum over all possible binary combinations (2N) with outcome k, each multiplied by the product of all N individual probabilities of the combined outcome.

Does this 'algorithm' have a name? How would this be written as a formula?

I am searching for something like: Probability of outcome K = Formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the [Poisson-Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). See [Efficiently computing poisson binomial sum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242233/efficiently-computing-poisson-binomial-sum)  and search this site!