# How to decide if Central Limit Theorem is applicable on a sum of Poisson variables?

Tags: poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I'm confused about the behaviour to expect from a large sum of independent and identically distributed Poisson variables.

- We know that a sum of $n$ Poisson variables of identical mean $\lambda$ is a Poisson variable of mean $n\lambda$.
- We also know from the Central Limit Theorem that if $n$ is large, this sum should be approximately normal of mean $n\lambda$ and variance $n\lambda$ as well.

Now, what if we set $n\lambda = 1$ for instance?

Does it mean that the $\lambda$ mean parameter cannot anymore be considered as finite when $n$ is large, so we cannot apply the CLT anymore? Because obviously, a $\mathcal{P}oisson(1)$ is different from a $\mathcal{N}(1,1)$...

---

**Context**: the concrete situation is from a model of evolution of DNA sequences:

we take a sequence of $n$ sites, and at each site, the number of mutations in a given time follows a Poisson distribution, but we know that over the whole sequence (e.g 200-1000 sites), the mean will be like 5 mutations in 1 million years. I feel like I can't apply the CLT, although in [a specific paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1055-7903(02)00268-3), the normality assumption is used to deduce confidence intervals.

Comment: A variety of approaches described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347 for sums of Binomial distributions apply to this question, too.  A search that includes [Berry Esseen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Berry+esseen+poisson) is also useful: it turned up the duplicate post.

Comment: I didn't know about Berry-Esseen. But why is it applicable here? Do you consider that each site process has an expectation of 0 ?

Comment: The only Poisson variable with an expectation of zero is the constant number zero, which will contribute nothing to a sum.  I wonder whether you might be confusing a Poisson *distribution* with a Poisson *process.*

Comment: Hmm, no I think I'm ok on that. I was just trying to understand why you linked my question with the Berry-Esseen theorem, but I just had an enlightenment now ^^

Comment: If $n\to\infty$ while $\lambda\downarrow0$ so that $n\lambda$ remains fixed, then the hypotheses of the central limit theorem are not satisfied. You need to look at what those hypotheses are. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's what I was worried about yes. And also I needed something less fuzzy to define "finite", since this could be a valid approx when $n\lambda$ > 10 apparently. However in this case, I grasp that the approximation has nothing to do with the CLT, but is more a property of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: It does have to do with the CLT. $\qquad$